# Display ViewModel value with @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Let's say my database has a reference table that maps the values `Zebra`, `Goat`, and `Dog` onto the keys `0`, `1`, and `2`, and a DropDownList where a user can select one of these values.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.Animal,
    new SelectList(
        new List<Object>{
            new {value = 0, text = "Zebra"},
            new {value = 1, text = "Goat"},
            new {value = 2, text = "Dog"}
        },
        "value",
        "text"
    ),
    new { @class = "form-control" }
)
```

After the user's selection is saved to the database, I'm trying to figure out a way to display the value for `m => m.Animal`.  It's saved as a `2`, but I want the displayed text to read `Dog`.  How do I set the default selected value on the @Html.DropFownListFor equal to the user's selection (e.g. `2`), so the selected item displays the text `Dog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm seeing two possible meanings to your question, so I guess I'll just cover them both.

If you're talking about making the drop down show the proper selected value, Razor should take care of this for you. However, the fact that you're defining the actual `SelectList` object, without specifying the `selectedValue` param, may be getting in the way. Technically `DropDownListFor` only needs `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, not an actual `SelectList`, and it's usually better to pass it the former as it's both easier and less prone to error:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.Animal,
    new List<SelectListItem> {
       new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Zebra" },
       new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Goat" },
       new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Dog" }
    },
    new { @class = "form-control" }
)
```

If, however, you're talking about how to translate the value `2` into `Dog` at some later point in your code, then you should actually employ something like an enum. For example:

```
public enum Animals
{
    Zebra = 0,
    Goat = 1,
    Dog = 2
}
```

Then, change your `Animal` property to be of this type:

```
public Animals Animal { get; set; }
```

Finally, and since you're running MVC5, you can just use:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Animal, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

You don't even need to pass a list of options because the helper will just get them from the enum the `Animal` property is typed to.

Then, when you want to display the selected animal type, you just use:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Animal)
```

And `Dog` or whatever it's set to will be output automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. `@Html.DropDownListFor` is weirdly intimidating and hard to approach.  I ended up fixing this particular problem by setting the selectedValue to `@Html.ValueFor(m => m.Animal)`, but this answer really helps me understand how to approach @Html.DropDownListFor correctly.